# Jquery click and delete cookie insert

Tags: javascript, cookies

Hi I have a code snippet in my class name cookie, but I have an error in my code I can not find it. Clicking the button again will delete this cookie, but all cookies will be deleted. Where's the problem?

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){

var elements = [];

$("a").click(function(){
var elementid =  $(this).attr("id");

    if ($("#"+elementid).hasClass("Active")) {
    $("#"+elementid).addClass("Active");
    $("#"+elementid).removeClass("Noactive");
    elements.push($(this).attr("id"));
    $.cookie("elements",JSON.stringify(elements),{expires:1});
    }else{
    $("#"+elementid).addClass("Noactive");
    $("#"+elementid).removeClass("Active");
    elements.push($(this).attr("id"));
    $.removeCookie("elements",JSON.stringify(elements),{expires:-1});
    }
   });

var elements = JSON.parse($.cookie('elements'));
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
$("#" + elements[i]).removeClass("Active");
$("#" + elements[i]).addClass("Noactive");
}
});
```

Comment: What is this   `$.removeCookie("elements",JSON.stringify(elements)` for?

Comment: This way all cookies are deleted. I just want to delete the active snack item.